# Custom javascript match not working on specific variables

Tags: javascript, regex, google-tag-manager

I have a very specific issue on custom javascript code in gtm.
I have a regex match that defines the output variable.

It works for 99% of the tests, but bugs on a few ones, and I have no idea why.

The goal is to format output value to use as a content grouping in GA.

Here are 2 of the strings that don't trigger the regex:

- Checkout-Login
- __SYSTEM__Page-Render

And here is the code :

```
if({{page_template}}.test(/(__SYSTEM__Page-Render|Blog)/g)){grouping = "Content pages";}
  else if({{page_template}}.test(/(Checkout|Shipping|Payment|Order)/g)){grouping = "Checkout";}
```

Would you have any idea why it doesn't work ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have the "g" flag on your regular expressions?

Comment: "doesn't work" is vague.  What are you expecting and what actually happened?

Comment: `.match()` is the wrong API to use here. If your intent is to perform a logic _test_, you should use an API call that returns a Boolean. That would be `RegEx.test()`. For short strings, Regex performance isn't as good as the String API methods - (like `.includes()`)

Comment: I edited my question. Regarding the "g", it might be useless, but I'm coming from PERL and regex are slightly different there. Should I take it off ?

Regarding .match and .test, I tried both, and neither work for these examples.

Comment: You'll need to provide a [example] that shows `.test()` not working please. You've given us very little to work with here: i.e. that's twice now for "doesn't work" without explanation.